# Is this damaged aluminium frame unsafe to use?

Tags: frames, damage, aluminum

[image]

Hello
I have a Giant Seek 3 aluminium frame where somehow the rear rim has rubbed the frame creating a hole as shown in the picture. On the other side there has also been some rubbing/scratching but it hasn't created a hole like this side.
I suspect it's unuseable/unsafe but just would like to confirm if anyone knows.

---

Update: Thanks all for your help.

I have decided to just salvage the parts off it and throw away the frame.

Comment: Just a heads up but, from a photograph, one can only really say "That looks unsafe" or "I can't tell." You might want to ask a couple of bike shops in your area. I, personally, wouldn't ride that bike any longer than I had to, and I'd be careful to avoid potholes, kerbs and so on.

Comment: If that hole was caused by that tyre rubbing, there's something badly wrong with your back wheel as well, because it must have moved quite a lot to the side. Or there was a wheel problem in the past and the wheel was fixed without checking the frame

Comment: If it were steel it could be fixed, but its not.  It looks like you're up for a new bike or at least a frame.  I suspect that chainstay would fold up a lot easier under pressure than the right-hand side.

Comment: [Stick a fork in that frame](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stick_a_fork_in_something) - it's done.

Comment: Don't bin it - send it to the local scrap man, or at least put it in the recycle.   Landfill is  a bad place for a bike.

Comment: Any chance you remember how thick was the tube at that point?

Answer (score 3):

If that's a chainstay/seatstay, then it really is unsafe.

With regards to @DavidRicherby and @ChrisH 's comments, I agree that you should go consult your LBS or any local frame builder. If you're lucky enough, it might just be salvaged by bridging/filling that hole by welding.

If you do plan to ride it in rough areas then I personally suggest you get a new bike frame instead. Fixed or not, the chain/seatstay is already probably compromised enough that I'd get off and lift that bike up every time I encounter a pothole or speed bump.

Comment: *it might just be salvaged by bridging/filling that hole by welding.*  Unfortunately, I suspect that's not likely to be successful with any recent aluminum frame, given how thin the frame elements are in order to save weight and how the aluminum alloy has likely been heat-treated to have the desired properties such as strength, stiffness, and toughness.

Comment: @AndrewHenle if it's the stays, then they're most likely designed for a bit of compliance in mind (rather than stiffness), but I agree that the tubing would have been so thinned out that welding might not be possible anymore. That is why I said 'might' and 'consult your LBS or any local frame builder' as I'm sure thay're qualified enough to have a final verdict.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing whether the frame material is 6061 or 7004 aluminum makes a huge difference, 7004 is laced with zinc and in that case scrapping it is your best option. If it is 6061 then welding is a viable option if you can afford it. Your frame, your call bro.

Comment: OP has already stated the frame was unsaveable.

Comment: Your responses in general could be improved by not using all caps and using proper punctuation. This would make them much easier to read. Note how they've been edited by other posters! This particular response could be improved if you explain why 6061 repairs are practical but 7005 isn't. Also, why does the presence of zinc in 7005 matter? Last, I'm aware that 7005 is used fairly often in bike parts and frames, but I'm not aware that 7004 is. Not sure if it's a typo.